# Swift 2: Type of expression is ambiguous without more context, for a dictionary

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

Why is the compiler throwing an error for the following code that attempts to create a dictionary?  How would you fix this code?

```
let options = [
  kCVPixelBufferCGImageCompatibilityKey: true,
  kCVPixelBufferCGBitmapContextCompatibilityKey: true]
```

I've looked through all of the other related questions with this same error and have not been able to find a solution.

Comment: What's that colon ':' doing after the name `options`?

Comment: @AlexBrown oops that was an artifact. fortunately the colon was not the root of the problem.

Comment: http://ericasadun.com/2015/10/19/sets-vs-dictionaries-smackdown-in-swiftlang/ ... This linked post defines an NSDictionary type for those same constants in Swift as `[NSString:NSObject]` though AnyObject might work better, depending on your needs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

```
let options : [NSObject : AnyObject] = [
    kCVPixelBufferCGImageCompatibilityKey: true,
    kCVPixelBufferCGBitmapContextCompatibilityKey: true]
```

`[NSObject : AnyObject]` is the equivalent to `NSDictionary` in Objective-C. The library you're using requires it to be of this type.

Comment: Thank you!  I wasn't aware [NSObject : AnyObject] was the NSDictionary equivalent, that's good to know.