# Swift 3 - Trying to cast a dictionary to CFDictionary

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary

When I'm trying to create an array as a CFDictionary, I'm getting an error (shown bellow).

This is the code:

```
let attrs = [kCVPixelBufferCGImageCompatibilityKey:kCFBooleanTrue,  kCVPixelBufferCGBitmapContextCompatibilityKey:kCFBooleanTrue] as CFDictionary
```

But the weird thing is that I'm using the same line of code in another project, without receiving any errors. What does the error mean?

> Error: Contextual type 'CFDictionary' cannot be used with dictionary literal

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/a/33246642/1187415 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use below code to convert the dictionary to `CFDictionary` as mention below:

```
let attrs = [kCVPixelBufferCGImageCompatibilityKey as String :kCFBooleanTrue,
             kCVPixelBufferCGBitmapContextCompatibilityKey as String:kCFBooleanTrue] as
        CFDictionary
```

Hope This will helps